# Get a Blender animation into 3DS Max

Tags: animation

I've been trying to get this to work for two days but no hope...

I've tried importing it as an obj file (and that works) but there is no animation
(side note I've also tried adding a cp2 file as well as the obj but I can't find where to put the file),

I've tried importing it as an fbx file but that won't load in 3DS Max.

Btw I'm using 3DS Max Lite that comes with After Effects (and I know that this isn't much info from 2 days but I was looking through every video I could and still couldn't find anything that helpful apart from https://vimeo.com/28146883 (again problem for this video is that I have a newer version of 3DS Max and I don't know how to add cp2 files))

Comment: Well if you want to export animations don't bother with OBJ at all, it does not support anything beyond geometry itself and basic materials. Your only option is as far as I know FBX, and even then don't expect a perfect point by point export. Make sure the version of max you are using does support animations.

Comment: Did you try the collada format??